# How can I take two mutable borrows from different parts of a vector?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Let's say I want to swap the first and third items of a vector using a bit-twiddling hack:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    {
        let first_item = &mut v[0];
        let third_item = &mut v[2];
        *first_item ^= *third_item;
        *third_item ^= *first_item;
        *first_item ^= *third_item;
    }

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Rust doesn't like this:

> ```
>    Compiling mcve v0.0.0 (/home/wizzwizz4/rust/mcve)
> error[E0499]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable more than once at a time
>  --> src/main.rs:6:31
>   |
> 5 |         let first_item = &mut v[0];
>   |                               - first mutable borrow occurs here
> 6 |         let third_item = &mut v[2];
>   |                               ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
> 7 |         *first_item ^= *third_item;
>   |         -------------------------- first borrow later used here
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
> error: Could not compile `mcve`.
>
> To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
> ```

That's fine, because I only really want to change `v[0]`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    {
        let first_item = &mut v[0];
        *first_item = v[2];
    }

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

I'm stuck again:

> ```
>    Compiling mcve v0.0.1 (/home/wizzwizz4/rust/mcve)
> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
>  --> src/main.rs:6:23
>   |
> 5 |         let first_item = &mut v[0];
>   |                               - mutable borrow occurs here
> 6 |         *first_item = v[2];
>   |         --------------^---
>   |         |             |
>   |         |             immutable borrow occurs here
>   |         mutable borrow later used here
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
> error: Could not compile `mcve`.
>
> To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
> ```

The thing is, *I* know that both of those borrows are from different parts of the vector. Specifically, I know that the first index is `<= 1`, and the second index is `> 1`.

How do I tell the Rust compiler this?

Comment: How am I _so bad at searching‽_ What is this, the third duplicate this week?

Comment: Granted, the site's search engine isn't very good. If you're searching on SO directly, I would recommend trying another search engine (Duck Duck Go or Google).

Comment: *I want to swap the first and third items of a vector* — [`swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap)

Comment: @Shepmaster This was merely a MCVE. It's the first that occurred to me… and also to the writer of the duplicate question, unsurprisingly.

Comment: I have `r foo` as a quick search in Firefox bound to `https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com rust foo`. In [this case](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com%20rust%20How%20can%20I%20take%20two%20mutable%20borrows%20from%20different%20parts%20of%20a%20vector), your question is first (exact match and all that), The next results ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48420218/155423); [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30073684/155423); [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26409316/155423); [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25531963/155423)) are all valid.

Comment: @Shepmaster Same with DDG… Never mind; I'm just bad at searching.